# Xdebug 3 doesn't connect in docker

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I used this docker-compose file with the Xdebug options that worked for me in a local Xdebug installation, but doesn't work in Docker.

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
    app:
        container_name: php7.3-xdebug
        image:  'php7.3-xdebug-i'
        ports: 
            - '9090:80'
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
        environment:
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: zend_extension=xdebug.so xdebug.mode=debug xdebug.start_with_request=yes xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
```

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3.28-apache-buster
RUN pecl install xdebug-3.0.4 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
COPY . /var/www/html
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
```

and this launch.json in VSCode:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}",
             },
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9003
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried a lot of configs but there is no way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
XDEBUG_CONFIG: zend_extension=xdebug.so xdebug.mode=debug
    xdebug.start_with_request=yes xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
```

This line is incorrect:

1. You can't load extensions through an Xdebug specific environment variable (but the `docker-php-ext-enable xdebug` line in your `Dockerfile` should have taken care of this already).
2. If you want to set settings through `XDEBUG_CONFIG`, then you should **not** prefix them with `xdebug.`, which is explained in the [documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#XDEBUG_CONFIG).
3. The documentation also says that only a select set of settings can be set through `XDEBUG_CONFIG`, and `start_with_request` is not one of these. It needs to be set in a PHP ini file.
4. To set Xdebug's **mode**, you need to use the `XDEBUG_MODE` environment variable instead, as is explained in the [documentation again](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode).